# iMessage application - Memory leak when display GIF as UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, gif, imessage

[image: Memory warning]

Hello guys, I got a problem with memory. I try to used [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to display GIF images as UICollectionViewCell. Each time I went back to previous ViewController and cameback to current one, the memory is growing up weirly (doubling). I am using RxSwift with some related libraries.

This is call giphy api source, and bind to collection view:

```
provider = RxMoyaProvider<Giphy>()
    giphyTrackerModel = GiphyTrackerModel(provider: provider, gifUrl: latestGiphyName)
    giphyTrackerModel
        .trackGiphy()
        .bindTo(collectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "SearchCell", cellType: SearchCell.self)) {
            (index, giphyDataModel, cell) in
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.giphy = giphyDataModel
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

This is my SearchCell.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher    
class SearchCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var gifImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        gifImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        gifImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.backgroundColor = Color.lightGray
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    }

    weak var giphy: GiphyDataModel! { 
        didSet {
            if let gifUrl = giphy.images?.downsized?.url { 
                 let url = gifUrl.characters.count != 0 ? URL(string: gifUrl) : URL(string: "")
                 gifImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check if your cell's delegate is a strong reference to self. That might cause a strong reference cycle instead of a memory leak. Though the better way is to use instruments to find out.

Comment: Thank @BenOng, I've tried to remove delegate. Memory leak still coming. Poor me :(

Comment: One another guys got the same [issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/4512hu/spent_all_day_on_playing_animated_gifs_in_a/) , but still no detail solution.

Comment: Well, based on what you showed, I can't offer a detailed solution either. If you haven't used instruments to find where the leaks are, you should do that first. Making sure what caused the memory to not be released is the first step to fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try use MSStickerView instead of UIImageView. It should reduce a little bit memory usage. Also it could be problem with caching files. You should check it.